# Select all 2nd cell values in a table to array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I am working on a requirement, where I need to push numbers in text boxes to an array. The text boxes are in the 2nd cell in the table row and 3rd cell is a date picker.

The code snippet below is giving me all text field values along with date values in array. I need only the values of the text fields to that array. Please help me with solution.

```
var NumbersArray = $('#myTable input[type=text]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(NumbersArray);
```

This piece of code below is also not working:

```
var secondCellContents = [],

$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $secondCell = $(this).children('td').eq(1).text(),
    secondCellContent = $secondCell.text();

  secondCellContents.push(secondCellContent);
});
console.log(secondCellContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing for 2nd cell also like:

```
var secondCellContents = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function() {
    return $('td:eq(1)', this).val();
}).get();

console.log(secondCellContents);
```

Also, the `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea and `.text()` is used to get the combined text contents of each element. The `.text()` method returns the value of text and CDATA nodes as well as element nodes.

Comment: @Palash This is not working array is undefined in output. Do I need to make any changes  to selection? "myTable" is Id attribute of the table in DOM

Comment: Can you pls post the html, so that I can see what is the content of your 2nd column actually?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make it work with your own code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var NumbersArray = $('#myTable td:nth-child(2) input[type="text"]').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  
  console.log(NumbersArray); 
  
  //OR
  
  var secondCellContents = [];

  $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
     var $secondCell = $(this).children('td:eq(1)');
     secondCellContent = $secondCell.find('input').val();
     secondCellContents.push(secondCellContent);
  });
  
  console.log(secondCellContents);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><input type='text' value="1" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><input type='text' value="2" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><input type='text' value="3" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have 2nd cell in the table and which is date picker. The Map function is returning both text field and date picker values.

Comment: Then you add `td:nth-child(2)` in your selector. I updated my answer.